# Key to the infinite

Tags: riddle, word

I hope you will like this riddle:

- I am an invisible key but I don't open a lock.
- I am infinite and I am growing faster than anything.
- You are in me but you cannot see me.
- You need me when there is too much going on around you.
- I am a physical quantity.

Who am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you...

> Space?

I am an invisible key but I don't open a lock.

> (Thanks, @WhatsUp!) Space is a key on the keyboard, but you can't see it when you type it. Shift or caps*lock* have no effect when used with space.

I am infinite and I am growing faster than anything.

> "Space" or "outer space" is constantly expanding, and there is no known limit to our universe.

You are in me but you cannot see me.

> Space is all around us (we are in it), but space is invisible.

You need me when there is too much going on around you.

> People say they "need space" or "give me space" when they get stressed or crowded.

I am a physical quantity.

> Not sure about this one, possibly space-time (any mathematical model which fuses the three dimensions of space and the one dimension of time into a single four-dimensional manifold)

Comment: I think the first sentence is refering to rot13(rot13(the space key on your keyboard)).

Comment: I love grilled cheese